# Why is my matrix value nil?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, null, lua-table

When I attempt to print the value of the table generated by `generateGrid` in Lua, I get a `nil` value (no errors). Why? Shouldn't it return a `displayObject` of some kind? Am I printing it incorrectly?

```
local function generateGrid (rows, cols)

    local grid = {}
    local gridPointRadius = 10 -- the display size for the grid points.
    local rowDist = display.contentWidth/(rows-1)
    local colDist = display.contentHeight/(cols-1)

    for row = 1, rows do 
        grid[row] = {}
        for col = 1, cols do

            testCircle =  display.newCircle(rowDist * (row-1), 
                                            colDist * (col-1), 
                                            gridPointRadius) -- ugliness occurs with the offsets and non-zero indexes. how do you prefer use positioning with offsets, when the starting index is 1?
            testCircle:setFillColor( 1,0,0,1 )
            grid[row].col = testCircle -- why does this work, but grid[row][column] does not?
        end
    end
    return grid
end

pathGrid = generateGrid(rowsForGrid, colsForGrid)
print(pathGrid[1][2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grid[row].col = testCircle
```

This line is the problem, `grid[row].col` is equivalent to `grid[row]["col"]`, which is obviously not what you want, change it to:

```
grid[row][col] = testCircle
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `generateGrid` is essentially the following:

```
for row = 1, rows do 
    grid[row] = {}
    for col = 1, cols do
        ...
        grid[row].col = display.newCircle(...)  
    end
end
return grid
```

There is no relationship between the "col" in `grid[row].col` and the `col` loop variable. The expression `grid[row].col` looks for a field called "col" in the object at `grid[row]` it is like writing `grid[row]["col"]`. So the code you posted stores every display object created in the loop in the same "bin", namely `grid[row]["col"]`. However, `print(pathGrid[1][2])` is attempting to access 2nd item of `grid[1]`, but there is none: the only item in `grid[1]` is a display object associated with field "col". So the print receives a nil, no error: in Lua it is not an error to get a value that does not exist, only if you try to call a nil value or access a field in it, and it is not an error to print nil. If the loop were fine, then you would want to do `print(pathGrid[1].col)`. Once you fix the loop, the print statement you have now will produce the expected output.

You also have a related question "why does this work, but grid[row][column] does not?": probably because it is not column but col that you should have used, `grid[row][col]`, if that is indeed what you used then it should have worked, and the problem related to this was elsewhere in your code.

Finally, you ask "ugliness occurs with the offsets and non-zero indexes. how do you prefer use positioning with offsets, when the starting index is 1?": there is no other way when you map ranges that start at 1 (rows and columns) to ranges that start at 0 (pixels on screen).

--

Comment: Thanks for your incredible attention to detail! The non-zero indexing drives me a bit nuts, but... :)